# java-facebook-api: is FB.Canvas.setAutoResize() implemented?

Tags: java, facebook

I'm Creating a facebook application using apache-tomcat.
I use the Java Facebook API.

It seems that the height of the facebook application window does not match the height of my application. i understood that in javascript there is the following command:

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize()
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize

this command creates an interval that makes sure that the height of the application matches the height the facebook provides me.

Is there a way to do that using the java facebook api ?

## update

I use the java facebook api from the following URL:

```
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/
```

thanks!

Comment: Which Java Facebook API are you using? There's no **official** Facebook SDK for Java but there are many flavours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link refers to the Facebook Javascript SDK. This is only convenient if your application will contain Facebook's iframe or Facebook Canvas to your presentation layer (jsp, html, etc.).

It's basically Javascript SDK to handle Facebook Objects on a presentation layer. Other than that, It's definitely not available on the Facebook Graph API or the Legacy Facebook API.